# Java: NullPointerException when trying to add object to BlockingQueue?

Tags: java, initialization, blockingqueue

I found a similar question about a PriorityQueue, the error with that one was that it wasn't initialized correctly. I might have the same problem, but i can't figure out how to initialize it correctly!

As of now i just do:

BlockingQueue myQueue = null;

but that throws an exception as soon as i try to add something to the list.

How do i correctly initialize a BlockingQueue?

Answer (score 3):

[`BlockingQueue<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) is an interface. You need to pick a specific implementation of that interface, such as [`ArrayBlockingQueue<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html), and invoke one of its [constructors](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#ArrayBlockingQueue%28int%29) like so:

```
BlockingQueue<E> myQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<E>(20);
```

If you're unsure what different types of blocking queues exist in the JDK, look under ["All Known Implementing Classes"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you call any method on null you will get a null pointer exception.
Try making a new ArrayBlockingQueue, which implements the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the javadocs which also has examples
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

BlockingQueue blockingQueue =
    new ArrayBlockingQueue(100); // there are other implementations as well, in particular that uses a linked list and scales better than the array one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make `BlockingQueue` hold a certain type, for example `BlockingQueue<String>` or something similar.
2. You need to initialize the variable with an implementation of `BlockingQueue`, for example `ArrayBlockingQueue<E>`.

So do something like:

```
BlockingQueue<MyObject> = new ArrayBlockingQueue<MyObject>();
```

and you'll be fine.